# How to store movie database if I would like to process it with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, database, sqlite, yaml

I would like to store the data of my favourite movies in some kind of database, however I have no clue how to do it. I attended computer science at university but one of the most blurry things to me was the theorem of databases... 
I want to store the title, year of production, makers, actors, short description, long description (multiline), links to cover image, links to screenshot images, etc.
My approaches:

- In separate text files, which can be parsed with regexes.
- In separate XML documents, which can be read / write with xml-simple Ruby gem.
- In separate files, which was dumped with pstore / JSON / YAML
- In a real database like SQLite, MySQL, etc.

Which one would be the most easy and convenient? Any other approaches to follow?

Comment: Thx, but which one? Any gem to use for?

Comment: For a simple thing like this that is for your use only (i.e. isn't going up to a server where it will see heavy load), use whatever database you already have running. To access it, use whatever ORM you already know or even raw SQL through the database's standard gem.

Comment: I have no database / gem installed, I have never used one.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a rails project, create model `Movie` and `movies_controller`, run a migration with all these fields you need (title, year of production, makers, actors, short description, long description (text), links to cover image, links to screenshot images) and you are set to go - default db is sqlite (since you don't have specific requirements to it), you can process the db as you wish.